# AWS LightSail RDS - How Much RAM Do I Need

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I'm just setting up a hight availability WordPress network and I need to decide how much RAM I need for the database instance. On a web server you run "top" and find out how much RAM is being used per MySql process and then look in your config file and look at the maximum number of processes that are allowed to run.

How do you calculate how much RAM you will need on a High availability MySQL database running in AWS LightSail? The plans seem very light on RAM. For example a $20 webserver gets 4GB of RAM whereas a $60 database server get 1GB of RAM. Why is this and how many processes will 1GB run?

Comment: DB usage with wordpress should actually be pretty light because with WP, you want aggressive caching (due to how slow WP is without it)

Comment: Good point @jordanm. 1GB still seems light to me though.